# Getting value of object from string in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a function which has 2 parameter like string and object, I want to read the string and get the values from the object like this;

if calling `test(text, info)` should return: `I started school at age 6 in Russia`

where

```
const text= 'I started school at age {info.age} in {info.country} 
const info= {age: 6, country: Russia}
```

So I wrote this function to find the substring between {} in string and then get its values from the object like this:

```
    const test = (str, object) => {
      return str.search(/{|}/g, '+')
    }
```

which returns `I started school at age + info.age + in + info.country` instead of `I started school at age 6 in Russia`

Comment: Check Template literals - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: _“but I get the string with +”_ - you have just discovered the difference between _code_, and _data_.

Answer (score 0):

Use Template literals.

const info = {age: 6, country: "Russia"};

const text = `I started school at age ${info.age} in ${info.country}`; // will produce "I started school at age 6 in Russia"

Comment: thats not the solution